# List values being replaced instead of being appended

Tags: python, list, loops

I am attempting to append a value #y that is calculated using the ODEINT onto a list called #y_list. i created a new function called #saves_vals which does this at every iteration point. The list is growing as the iterations run(which is good) however the new value of #y replaces all the values previously generated. i have attempted to create a copy of the #y values using #y[:] however this continues to fail. i am fairly new to python. please assist

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

```
y_list =[]
def saves_vals(list_y,y):
    print (" the value of y being used now is " +str(y))
    list_y.append(y[:])
    print ( " this is the y_list, as it grows " + str(list_y))
return (list_y)

def model(y,t):
    k= saves_vals(y_list,y)
    dydt =  - 2.0 *y
    return dydt

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y_0 = 10
y = odeint(model,y_0,t)

plt.figure(figsize =(4,4))
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.show()
```

i am expecting the list of the y values to grow as the iterations progress however to keep the results of the past iterations for later comparison

Comment: Slicing a NumPy array doesn't make a copy.

Comment: thank you so much @user2357112.i was hesitating to join this forum but now i see thats one of the best decisions i have made recently